# Mercurial Integration with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, mercurial

Is there a way to automatically run the update command after issuing the Team -> Share -> Pull from default command from the menu? TortoiseHg has a configure repository option for the Synchronize command, but I believe this will only apply when using the Hg Explorer Integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do the following...

1. select a project in the hg repository that you want to 'update'
2. Use the Fetch item from the Team menu (on the 'main menu bar).